# How to get/set data from/to each page of ViewPager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Will try to explain what I need to achieve:

My activity is used to display some user settings. Just for users, to make it look nicer, I need to use ViewPager with 3 pages: general settings, another settings, different settings. When activity starts I get all settings using http async task. So i need to fill all my 3 pages with the data from http responce. So user can scroll left/right to view different pages and change settings. On action bar I have button save: when press it, it should take all the data from each page and send http post request in order to save data.

Which type of adapter do I need to use for my ViewPager in order to achieve it? Currently I use "FragmentStatePagerAdapter", but it gives me access to the current/displayed fragment. But  I need to be able to get/set data from every fragment, not only current one.

Can someone give me any hint how I can do that. Shoul I use FragmentStatePagerAdapter or just PagerAdapter will be enough? Or maybe there is another way for it)

Any tips will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Loading the data and displaying it are different tasks. You can of course download all the data that you will need and store it in the adapter itself. Once the adapter gets a call to `getItem()` you initialize a new fragment with the data for the given page and return it.
Also, use a [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) because it is a lot more lightweight. In the api docs you can actually see how a new Fragment is created an returned.

Comment: so, I need to work with each fragment independently, right? When user press save button, it should get each fragment and get data from each view of each fragment one by one?

Comment: Yea. or you just save the data to a central point. Fragments can get the activity and call methods there.

Comment: How I can access to the views of current fragment from onOptionsItemSelected ?

mAdapter.getItem(pager.getCurrentItem()).getView() return NULL.

Comment: a fragment does not have a view at all times - only after onCreateView. you should not want to get the view anyway, just set the variables once the ui changes via callbacks and so on.